# Retrieve Google Client ID and Client Secret Azure Authentication

Tags: azure, authentication, asp.net-core-mvc

I obviously don't want to hard code these values, but I am not sure how to get the stored values in Azure.

This is what I have been doing locally for my app secrets in ASP.NET Core...

```
app.UseGoogleAuthentication(new GoogleOptions()
{
    ClientId = Configuration["Authentication:Google:ClientId"],
    ClientSecret = Configuration["Authentication:Google:ClientSecret"]
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are going to host those on Azure WebApps you can use App Settings (they basically are environment variables) to store that data. Take a look here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/web-sites-configure#application-settings